# Solr Index file removing html tags and garbage content form indexing

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene

I am working on Solr 6.5, and one thing I noticed is that my index file size keeps on increasing with content. I have used a stop word file and no common words are indexed.

I see many HTML tags in the index, which I do  not want to index, as well as comments in content which should not be indexed. How can I find these and update my stopword txt to handle them?

I have indexed english content only, and the index file is already 30 GB, with only 9 million documents.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [HTMLStripFilterFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/charfilterfactories.html#CharFilterFactories-solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory) to remove all HTML content when indexing.

But 30GB for 9 million documents is just under 4kb per document, which isn't really that much. These documents *do* have an inherent size, so they will add data to the index as long as you're indexing them.